TypeError: Channel.stream_stream() got an unexpected keyword argument '_registered_method'
Trying to use fabric-sdk-py repo by cloning. Completed "make install" successfully but then when tried to use the library got below traceback
code related to the traceback is
>>> from hfc.fabric import Client

>>> cli = Client(net_profile="test/fixtures/network.json")

>>> print(cli.organizations)  # orgs in the network

>>> print(cli.peers)  # peers in the network

>>> print(cli.orderers)  # orderers in the network

>>> print(cli.CAs)  # ca nodes in the network

OS : MS Windows 8.1 x64
Using Docker Toolbox as Docker Desktop requires atleast version Windows 10
Python version :
!python --version
Python 3.12.4

>>> pip list
>>> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.Package Version

aiogrpc 1.8alabaster 0.7.16arrow 1.3.0astroid 3.2.2asttokens 2.4.1atomicwrites 1.4.1attrs 23.2.0autopep8 2.0.4Babel 2.14.0backports.tarfile 1.0.0bcrypt 4.1.3beautifulsoup4 4.12.3binaryornot 0.4.4black 24.4.2bleach 6.1.0Brotli 1.1.0certifi 2024.7.4cffi 1.16.0chardet 5.2.0charset-normalizer 3.3.2click 8.1.7cloudpickle 3.0.0colorama 0.4.6comm 0.2.2cookiecutter 2.6.0cryptography 42.0.8debugpy 1.8.2decorator 5.1.1defusedxml 0.7.1diff-match-patch 20230430dill 0.3.8distlib 0.3.8docstring-to-markdown 0.15docutils 0.21.2entrypoints 0.4exceptiongroup 1.2.0executing 2.0.1fastjsonschema 2.20.0filelock 3.15.4flake8 7.0.0grpcio 1.64.1 grpcio-tools 1.64.1 h2 4.1.0hkdf 0.0.3hpack 4.0.0hyperframe 6.0.1idna 3.7imagesize 1.4.1importlib_metadata 8.0.0importlib_resources 6.4.0inflection 0.5.1intervaltree 3.1.0ipykernel 6.29.5ipython 8.26.0isort 5.13.2jaraco.classes 3.4.0jaraco.context 5.3.0jaraco.functools 4.0.0

jedi 0.19.1jellyfish 1.0.4Jinja2 3.1.4jsonschema 4.22.0jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1jupyter_client 8.6.2jupyter_core 5.7.2jupyterlab_pygments 0.3.0keyring 25.2.1lark 1.1.9markdown-it-py 3.0.0MarkupSafe 2.1.5matplotlib-inline 0.1.7mccabe 0.7.0mdurl 0.1.2mistune 3.0.2more-itertools 10.3.0mypy-extensions 1.0.0nbclient 0.10.0nbconvert 7.16.4nbformat 5.10.4nest_asyncio 1.6.0numpydoc 1.7.0packaging 24.1pandocfilters 1.5.0paramiko 3.4.0parso 0.8.4pathspec 0.12.1pexpect 4.9.0pickleshare 0.7.5pip 24.0pkgutil_resolve_name 1.3.10platformdirs 4.2.2pluggy 1.5.0ply 3.11prompt_toolkit 3.0.47protobuf 5.27.0 psutil 6.0.0ptyprocess 0.7.0pure-eval 0.2.2pycodestyle 2.11.1pycparser 2.22pycryptodomex 3.20.0pydocstyle 6.3.0pyflakes 3.2.0Pygments 2.18.0pylint 3.2.5pylint-venv 3.0.3pyls-spyder 0.4.0PyNaCl 1.5.0PyQt5 5.15.9PyQt5-sip 12.12.2PyQtWebEngine 5.15.4PySocks 1.7.1python-dateutil 2.9.0python-lsp-black 2.0.0python-lsp-jsonrpc 1.1.2python-lsp-server 1.11.0python-slugify 8.0.4pytoolconfig 1.2.5pytz 2024.1pywin32 306pywin32-ctypes 0.2.2PyYAML 6.0.1pyzmq 26.0.3QDarkStyle 3.2.3qstylizer 0.2.3QtAwesome 1.3.1qtconsole 5.5.2QtPy 2.4.1referencing 0.35.1requests 2.32.3rich 13.7.1rope 1.13.0rpds-py 0.18.1Rtree 1.2.0Rx 3.2.0safe-pysha3 1.0.4setuptools 70.1.1sip 6.7.12six 1.16.0snowballstemmer 2.2.0sortedcontainers 2.4.0soupsieve 2.5Sphinx 7.3.7sphinxcontrib-applehelp 1.0.8sphinxcontrib-devhelp 1.0.6sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp 2.0.5sphinxcontrib-jsmath 1.0.1sphinxcontrib-qthelp 1.0.7sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.10spyder 5.5.5spyder-kernels 2.5.2stack-data 0.6.2tabulate 0.9.0text-unidecode 1.3textdistance 4.6.2three-merge 0.1.1tinycss2 1.3.0toml 0.10.2tomli 2.0.1tomlkit 0.12.5tornado 6.4.1traitlets 5.14.3types-python-dateutil 2.9.0.20240316typing_extensions 4.12.2ujson 5.10.0urllib3 2.2.2virtualenv 20.26.3watchdog 4.0.1wcwidth 0.2.13webencodings 0.5.1whatthepatch 1.0.5wheel 0.43.0win-inet-pton 1.1.0yapf 0.40.1zipp 3.19.2zstandard 0.22.0

To generate a initial network in Hyperledger Fabric
